# count event frequency per users using calculated field

Tags: syntax, looker-studio

Google analytics have an `Event Action` Dimension, `Users` metrics, and `Total Events` metrics. I want to try calculate a frequency of users who download video more than 1 video/day using data studio. And I already put the tracker in `Event Action` as `DL_End`.

but I always failed when trying to make a syntax for calculated field.

this is some syntax that I used but all of them doesn't work:

```
Event Action = "DL_End" && Total Events > 1
```

```
Event Action = "DL_End" AND Total Events > 1
```

```
CASE
 WHEN Event Action In ("DL_End") AND Total Events > 1 THEN Users
END
```

Is there Any syntax that I can Use to calculate a frequency of users who download video more than 1 video/day? Is it Even possible to do it in data studio? if it can, can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create some changes under the visualization with some extra filters.
Try to add a filter to Event Action which Includes the `Event Action` that only contains `Event Action` required and add the `user` and `total events` metrics under a tabular chart first, which might give you some idea of the frequency of `users` associated with the `Event Action`

[image]

Once you get this, you will get an idea of how to distribute this into the time series.

[image]